# What alternatives to mousejoint are there?

Tags: box2d

I want to have a mousejoint for my player, but I read that it shouldn't be used in this case. The only other way I can think of creating it is by getting location of touch input and taking away the current location of player and then setting linear velocity equal to it. Can you think of any other ways? Cheers.

Comment: If mouse joint works, I'd say just use it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more further xplanation would help according to me. I suggest you may transfrom your body to touch point as i do in my game.

```
-(void) transFormBodyToPos:(CGPoint) pos{
     body->SetTransform(b2Vec2(pos.x/PTM_RATIO, pos.y/PTM_RATIO), 0);
}
```

and call it in touch moved

```
    CGPoint location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:touch.view]];
touchLocation = location;
[classCharacter transFormBodyToPos:touchLocation];
```